# Responsive form - controlling height of a textarea

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea, alignment

I've got this **HTML** form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="cf">
    <div class="left">
        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" id="first-name" required />
        <label for="last-name">Middle Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="middle-name" placeholder="Middle Name" id="middle-name" />
        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" id="last-name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <label for="details">Details</label>
        <textarea name="details" placeholder="Details" id="details" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

And this is my **CSS**:

```
/* Clearfix */
.cf:before,.cf:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.cf:after { clear: both; }

form > * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
}

.right {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .2);
}

form {
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    form {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
    }

    .left {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .right {
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
    }

    input[type="submit"] {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/gRRmh/

Basically it's three text input fields, one textarea and one submit button (aka input type submit). When the breakpoint is reached, the form flows into a two column layout. That's the part that is working.

The part that is not working is the height of the textarea. I want it to be the same height as the three input fields on the left.
Setting it to `height: 100%;` does not work for two reasons:

- The height of the label needs to be taken into account. Sure I could just give it a height in percentages and subtract that value from the textarea's height (10% / 90%) ...
- ...but for this to work, one parent elements needs a fixed height, so I need to give the form e.g. a height of 200px. The problem with that is I actually need to match the height of the left column by hand which isn't really a good solution.

So what I am actually looking for is something like the following, just without nudging pixels by hand:
[image]
(also with fiddle if you want, but please note: Its a bit messy. http://jsfiddle.net/mnBEh/1/)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you okay with the textarea shrinking size once it breaks and flows underneath, or did you still want the height of the text area to match the input section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only posible by giving manually height to textarea.So give height to textarea on media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It uses CSS tables, but I think it gets the result you're looking for, by setting the textarea to be 100% height, and then minusing the height of it's label. But for some reason, the height is only calculating correctly in Chrome, even though the other browsers supposedly support it.
http://jsfiddle.net/73cyorL1/

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    background: red;
}
.right {
    background: blue;
}
label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
form {
    background: grey;
}
input[type="text"], textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    background: #ccc;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
input[type="text"]:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #ddd;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .left {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table-cell
    }
    .right {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table-cell;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    textarea {
        height: calc(100% - 0.75em);
        /* 100% fill height, minus height of details label */
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" id="first-name" required="required" />
            <label for="last-name">Middle Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="middle-name" placeholder="Middle Name" id="middle-name" />
            <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" id="last-name" required="required" class="last" />
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <label for="details">Details</label>
            <textarea name="details" placeholder="Details" id="details" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set "box-sizing: border-box;" and it will works