# How to change the size of a flask form field in connection with Bootstrap?

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-5

**forms.py**

```
class Form_Support(FlaskForm):
    
    message = StringField(label='Nachricht', validators=[Length(min=2, max=1000), DataRequired()])
    submit_message = SubmitField(label='Eingabe')
```

**index.html**

```
...
<div class="row">  
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            
            <form  method="POST" >
               
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                
                {{ form.message(class="form-control", placeholder="Ihre Nachricht") }}

                {{ form.submit_message(class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary", style="background-color: #6941c6; border:none; color: #f9f5ff; margin-left: 1vw;" )}}
            </form>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Result**
[image]

**How can I make the text field larger(higher)? I have already tried to use an own class instead of the form-control but without success.**

Comment: When you say larger, do you mean height?

Comment: Yes, I mean i want to get it higher

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the height of the text area by specifying (or increasing) the rows attribute using html 'textarea' tag as follows,

```
<form  method="POST" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea type="text" placeholder="Ihre Nachrichten" rows="10" columns="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">            

</form>
```

References:

1. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/textarea/
2. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/overview/
3. [Responsive form - controlling height of a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523319/responsive-form-controlling-height-of-a-textarea)